# UIActivityViewController with UISimpleTextPrintFormatter shows blank on dark mode

Tags: ios

The original question was about a problem in read device vs the Simulator, but I realized that the difference was that the device was in Dark Mode and the simulator was not. After that, I was able to reproduce in the Simulator. This is probably an Apple bug.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var manager = Manager()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Print something") {
                manager.share()
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $manager.showingShare) {
            ActivityView(items: manager.items)
        }
    }
}

class Manager: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var showingShare = false
    
    let items = [UISimpleTextPrintFormatter(text: "This is a test\nThis is a test\nThis is a test\nThis is a test")]
    
    func share() {
        showingShare.toggle()
    }
}

struct ActivityView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    let items: [UISimpleTextPrintFormatter]
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIActivityViewController {
        UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, context: Context) {}
}
```

This is the result in Dark Mode (on a real device):
[image: Printing on a real device]

Dark Mode OFF (on a Simulator):
[image: Printing on a Simulator]

Turning Dark Mode on/off will reproduce the issue on a Simulator. My guess is the there's a white text color on a white page in Dark Mode.

Comment: The issue is mentioned here too: https://github.com/Automattic/simplenote-ios/issues/447 with a fix (by subclassing `UISimpleTextPrintFormatter` and checking if in Dark Mode..

Answer (score 1):

While [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisimpletextprintformatter/1621830-color?language=objc) for `-[UISimpleTextPrintFormatter color]` states:

> If the value of this property is nil (the default), UIKit uses a black color when printing.

It seems the default value is not `nil`, but `labelColor` (as of iOS 17):

```objectivec
UISimpleTextPrintFormatter * printFormatter = [[UISimpleTextPrintFormatter alloc] initWithText:@"YOUR TEXT HERE"];
```

```objectivec
(lldb) po printFormatter.color
<UIDynamicCatalogSystemColor: 0x282d9c3c0; name = labelColor>
```

which of course is white in dark mode.

This seems like a bug, since the page color is always white by default, so I submitted this feedback:

> FB13418343: UISimpleTextPrintFormatter erroneously uses white text instead of black in dark mode (not printer-specific)

A simple workaround is to just set the `.color` property to `nil`:

```
printFormatter.color = nil; // FB13418343 default is labelColor (i.e. white in Dark Mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a workaround, but the text color can `UISimpleTextPrintFormatter` can be mutated.

```swift
let textFormatter = UISimpleTextPrintFormatter(text: someString)

if UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle == .dark {
    textFormatter.color = .black
}
```

Or with extension:

```swift
extension UISimpleTextPrintFormatter {
    
    func updateColorIfInDarkMode() {
        if UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle == .dark {
            color = .black
        }
    }
}
```

What I would *really want to change* is the actual the 'paper' color, (without it affecting the printing of course), but I don't think I can.